# How can I convert JS object into a valid JSON file and retrieve it back using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to the world of JS, and JSON.
In my JS file - I have

```
var data = {

      "A":{"section_num":"2.2", "problem_set":"Same", "start_time":"7/20/2015 10:00 am", "student_am":"9", "due_time":"7/20/2015 11:00 am", "submit":"9", "avg_score":"71", "danger":"5", "danger_list":"5,10,15,19,23", "warning":"8", "warning_list":"3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22", "success":"12", "success_list":"1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25"},

      "B":{"section_num":"2.3", "problem_set":"Not the same", "start_time":"6/19/2015 1:00 pm", "student_am":"23", "due_time":"6/19/2015 2:00 pm", "submit":"7", "avg_score":"82", "danger":"10", "danger_list":"11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "warning":"10", "warning_list":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", "success":"5", "success_list":"21,21,23,24,25"},

      "C":{"section_num":"2.4", "problem_set":"Math", "start_time":"6/20/2015 2:00 pm", "student_am":"23", "due_time":"6/20/2015 3:00 pm", "submit":"3", "avg_score":"82", "danger":"0", "danger_list":"", "warning":"10", "warning_list":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", "success":"15", "success_list":"11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25"},

       "D":{"section_num":"2.5", "problem_set":"Anything", "start_time":"6/20/2015 7:00 am", "student_am":"25", "due_time":"6/20/2015 8:00 am", "submit":"9", "avg_score":"98", "danger":"5", "danger_list":"1,2,3,4,5", "warning":"0", "warning_list":"", "success":"20", "success_list":"6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25"}
    };
```

---

## I want

to move this data to an external JSON file - so I can make an AJAX request to it.

How do I accomplish something that ?

Where should I start ?

Can someone please teach me how to do this or direct me to the right direction ?

Comment: https://www.lennu.net/jquery-ajax-example-with-json-response/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JSON file

This is what you put in some file, like `data.json`:

```
    {
      "A":{"section_num":"2.2", "problem_set":"Same", "start_time":"7/20/2015 10:00 am", "student_am":"9", "due_time":"7/20/2015 11:00 am", "submit":"9", "avg_score":"71", "danger":"5", "danger_list":"5,10,15,19,23", "warning":"8", "warning_list":"3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22", "success":"12", "success_list":"1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25"},

      "B":{"section_num":"2.3", "problem_set":"Not the same", "start_time":"6/19/2015 1:00 pm", "student_am":"23", "due_time":"6/19/2015 2:00 pm", "submit":"7", "avg_score":"82", "danger":"10", "danger_list":"11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "warning":"10", "warning_list":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", "success":"5", "success_list":"21,21,23,24,25"},

      "C":{"section_num":"2.4", "problem_set":"Math", "start_time":"6/20/2015 2:00 pm", "student_am":"23", "due_time":"6/20/2015 3:00 pm", "submit":"3", "avg_score":"82", "danger":"0", "danger_list":"", "warning":"10", "warning_list":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", "success":"15", "success_list":"11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25"},

      "D":{"section_num":"2.5", "problem_set":"Anything", "start_time":"6/20/2015 7:00 am", "student_am":"25", "due_time":"6/20/2015 8:00 am", "submit":"9", "avg_score":"98", "danger":"5", "danger_list":"1,2,3,4,5", "warning":"0", "warning_list":"", "success":"20", "success_list":"6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25"}
    }
```

### jQuery AJAX call

If your `data.json` is in the same directory as your HTML file then you can use this code to get it:

```
$.get('data.json')
  .done(function (data) {
    // you can use your data here
  })
  .fail(function () {
    // something went wrong
  });
```

(You tagged your question with "jquery" so I'm using jQuery here.)

### MIME type

Make sure that your server serves the file with a correct MIME type: **application/json** (see [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) and [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)).

### JSON syntax

Keep in mind that JSON data has a stricter syntax than JavaScript object literals. In your case this happens to be valid JSON but not every JavaScript object is valid JSON - for example you need to always quote keys with double quotes etc. - see: [json.org](http://json.org/) for details.

### Note on paths

The path in `$.get('path')` can be for example:

1. `'data.json'`
2. `'path/data.json'`
3. `'/path/data.json'`

Let's say that you access an HTML web page as:

`http://www.example.com/something/page.html`

This page includes some JavaScript file that makes an AJAX request. For the above 3 examples it will try to load, respectively:

1. `http://www.example.com/something/data.json` (for `'data.json'`)
2. `http://www.example.com/something/path/data.json` (for `'path/data.json'`)
3. `http://www.example.com/path/data.json` (for `'/path/data.json'`)

To look at it another way. If you include your JavaScript in the HTML file as, for example:

```
<script src="some/path/file.js"></script>
```

and you have your `data.json` in the same place as your JavaScript file, then you should make an AJAX call to:

```
$.get('some/path/data.json')
```

The paths are relative to your web page, in the same way as the paths in your `<script>` tags.

### Protocols

Note that it will not work over the [file: protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). You need a real protocol like HTTP or HTTPS, ie. you need to serve your files with a Web server, not access them on your local file system.

### More info

See also some relevant jQuery documentation:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
- https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: I tried your solution, and I keep failing. I moved my data out as you suggested, and through in its path in the `.get()` function. like this `$.get('/src/main/webapp/resources/js/reports/section-exercise/data-r.json')`

Comment: The path in `$.get()` should be relative to your HTML file. For example if your JS code is included in `index.html` and it is in `/src/main/webapp/resources/index.html` then it should be `$.get('js/reports/section-exercise/data-r.json')` or if absolute then it should be relative to your web server root directory. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `var data =` from your code and save the file to something like "data.json". Then put that file somewhere on your web server and call it via ajax.

UPDATE
if you use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your/json/file.json',
  type: 'get',
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific ? Now, I just created a new .json file and I store them in `/src/main/webapp/resources/js/reports/section-exercise/data-r.json` - how do I load that back in ?